# When is $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$?

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

The following question cropped up in a physics context when studying some properties of conformal field theory. I know a little Galois Theory, but not enough to be able to answer it, though I suspect it is elementary.

When $n$ is a multiple of $8$, we can see that $\sqrt{2}$ lies in the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ thanks to the identity

$$ \sqrt{2} = \zeta_n^{n/8} + \zeta_n^{-n/8} $$

Experiments with Sage seem to suggest that these are also the *only* values of $n$ for which this is true. Is this correct, and if so how does one prove it?

Moreover, in the interests of others viewing this question, is there a straightforward generalisation to other quadratic irrationals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the intersection $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)\cap \mathbb Q(\zeta_n)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{\gcd(m,n)})$ (for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291029/intersection-of-cyclotomic-fields)), it suffices to show that $\sqrt2$ is not contained in any cyclotomic field strictly inside $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)$. The largest such field is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_4)=\mathbb Q(i)$, and it's clear that $\sqrt2$ is not in this field (since the only reals in $\mathbb Q(i)$ are the rationals), so the only $n$ for which $\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ are multiples of $8$.

For the more general case of $\sqrt{m}$ with $m=\pm p_1\cdots p_s$, we can use that, for an odd prime $p$,
$$\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p}\in\mathbb Q(\zeta_p).$$
(This can be proven, for example, by using [Gauss sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum).) From this, we definitely get that
$$\sqrt m\in\mathbb Q(\zeta_{4|m|}),$$
since $\sqrt{\pm p_i}$ is in this field for all $i$ (since if $2|m$, $8|4m$, this is true for $p=2$ as well). If $m$ is odd and of correct sign, i.e.
$$m=\prod_{i=1}^s (-1)^{\frac{p_i-1}{2}}p_i,$$
then we can reduce $4|m|$ to $|m|$.

We can prove that this in fact optimal by strong induction on $s$. For the base case, we need only worry about factors of $p$ or $4p$, and so the cases aren't that bad since $\sqrt{\pm p}$ isn't in $\mathbb Q(i)$ regardless of $p$ and $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2n})$ for all odd $n$. For the inductive step, using any factor of $|m|$ or $4|m|$ either reduces the numbers of factors of $2$ (in which case arguments similar to the base case work) or removes a subset of the prime factors, in which case our strong inductive hypothesis can be used directly.

Comment: "$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2n})$ for all $n$" - you mean for odd $n$.

Comment: And just to make it fully self-contained, a reference for the first displayed equation is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum.

Comment: @PhilipBoyleSmith Thanks for the correction and the link. I've added the link to the answer.