# Proving $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \iff n = 8 \cdot m$ for $ m \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, complex-numbers, cyclotomic-fields

My ultimate goal is showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \iff n = 8 \cdot m$ for $ m \in \mathbb{N}$. I have showed that for $n= 8 \cdot m$ the result holds. There is only one direction left to show.

I was wondering if there is an elementary proof showing that $\sqrt 2$ is no element of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ if $n = l \cdot m +k $ for $m,l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ k \in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}$. Since that would solve the problem immediately.
I know it is proven here([When is $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954439/when-is-sqrt2-in-mathbbq-zeta-n)) however, the proves relies heavily on the fact that $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{gcd(m,n)})$, which the proofs use Galois theory which has yet to be developed in class. My idea was using the identities with $sin$ and $cos$ for $e^{ix}$, yet I hadn't had much success.
A different strategy, has been showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$ is a vectorspace of dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and than showing that the intersection for any $m$ is exactly the gcd. However, I have not made any progress using $sin$ and $cos$ identities.
Is there a better strategy utilizing the fact that we can work with $n=8$ in proving this identity $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{gcd(m,n)})$ or a better strategy in solving the entire problem.

Comment: The intersection of cyclotomic fields is not so hard to show, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291029/intersection-of-cyclotomic-fields) for example. No Galois theory is needed (this was exactly asked in this question, how to prove it without it).

Comment: Could you explain why we obtain the inequality for the  degree of the field extension?

Comment: I don't see any inequality here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the discriminant of a field extension?

Comment: @Servaes No I am not