# Understanding Neukirch´s proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-fields

I´m studying algebraic number theory from Neukirch´s book. I´m reading the Proposition 10.2 which says:

*A $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring $O$ of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is given by $1, \zeta, \zeta^2,..., \zeta^{d-1}$, with $d=\varphi(n)$, in other words, $O=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.*

In one step of the proof, the author mentions, if $n=l_1^{\nu_1}...l_r^{\nu_r}$ and $\zeta_i=\zeta^{n/l_i^{\nu_i}}$ is a primitive $l_i^{\nu_i}$-th root of unity, one has

$\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_1)...\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_r)$, with $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_1)...\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{i-1}) \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_i)=\mathbb{Q}$.

This is the step I cannot see. Could anyone explain me why these equalities holds? I''ll really appreciate this help!

Comment: I think one part of the argument is that you should write $1$ as a linear combination with integer coefficients of the $n/l_i^{\nu_i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cyclotomic fields in general we have $\mathbb{Q}_a\mathbb{Q}_b=\mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_a\cap\mathbb{Q}_b=\mathbb{Q}_{\gcd(a,b)}$. The first statement is fairly elementary, while the second is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291029/intersection-of-cyclotomic-fields) for instance.
For more than two fields, you use induction.