# $\mathbb{Q}(w_m) \cap \mathbb{Q}(w_n)=\mathbb{Q}$ when $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Lang's Chapter 6, Corollary 3.2 states that

> if $m,n$ are relatively prime, integers greater than $1$, then
> $$\mathbb{Q}(w_m) \cap \mathbb{Q}(w_n)=\mathbb{Q}$$ where $w_m$ is the primitive $mth$ root of unity.

Again the proof is not clear. It states that $ \mathbb{Q}(w_m) \mathbb{Q}(w_n)=\mathbb{Q}(w_{mn})$ and says it follows from the multiplicatively of Euler Totient Function. I couldn't understand how it follows immediately.

What I decoded is the following.

> (1)-I will show that $ \mathbb{Q}(w_m) \mathbb{Q}(w_n)=\mathbb{Q}(w_{mn})$

Proof of (1)-Its trivial that $\mathbb{Q}(w_{mn})$ contains both $\mathbb{Q}(w_{m})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(w_{n})$

On the other hand, it is sufficent to show that $\mathbb{Q}(w_{m})\mathbb{Q}(w_{n})$ contains a primitive root of unity. Infact $w_m w_n$ works for us. When $(m,n)=1$, we do have this result. It can be seen by writting the primitive root of unity as a power of $e$.

But how does it imply that

$$\mathbb{Q}(w_m) \cap \mathbb{Q}(w_n)=\mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: How are $w_m$ and $w_n$ defined?

Comment: What is the product of two fields?

Comment: that's compositium of two fields in an algebraic closure.

Comment: @DanielHast, those are primitive $mth$ and $nth$ roots of unity.

Comment: Guessing that you are talking about cyclotomic fields, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291029/intersection-of-cyclotomic-fields) is a duplicate.

Comment: @lulu, right. I searched but I think I need to search deeper.

Comment: Does Lang really use $w_n$ to denote a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity?  I think $\zeta_n$ is more conventional.

Comment: yeah, it is more conventional but I am working from my mobile and I was a bit unsure about the tex for that.

Comment: $\zeta$ should work